# Looking for code that allows me to make a dropdown appear if and only if a certain option in a prior dropdown is selected

Tags: html

Let me start off by saying I am a complete amateur at this kind of thing and have never done it before. I am trying to get a dropdown to appear if a certain option is selected in a previous dropdown.

Here is the first drop down:

```
        <label>
        Please select a metal type
        </label>
        <br /><select required=""class="required" id="metal type"
        name="properties[_Please select a metal type]">
        <option value="Blank"></option>
        <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
        <option value="Platinum">Platinum</option>
        <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
        <option value="Other2">Other</option>
        </select>
```

I want to have a second dropdown appear when the "Gold" option is selected. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you started to learn Javascript yet? If not, that's step 1. HTML alone cannot solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is beyond the basic capabilities of HTML. You can do this with simple Javascript snippet that will compare the value of your first select and then adjusts CSS of the second one to make it visible or not. These are basic things you should know about web development so i'll explain my reasoning about this solution below.

Programming the solution in JS is the best option for you because it requires no installation of any software or compiler, all browsers handle it out of the box and it can be done with just a few lines. The whole thing is simplified to improve your understading of it, however if you just copypaste it into txt file and change the extention to .html it will be fully functional. Play with it and adjust to your desire!

See the code blow:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <style>
      .visible {
        display: inline;
      }
      .hidden {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <select id="primary" onclick="checkSecondary()">
      <option value="silver">Silver</option>
      <option value="gold">Gold</option>
    </select>
    <select id="secondary" class="hidden">
      <option value="fish">Fish</option>
      <option value="goose">Goose</option>
    </select>
    ...
    <script>
      function checkSecondary(){
        var primary = document.getElementById("primary")
        var secondaryClasses = document.getElementById("secondary").classList
        if(primary.value == "gold"){
          secondaryClasses.remove("visible")
          secondaryClasses.add("hidden")
        }else{
          secondaryClasses.remove("hidden")
          secondaryClasses.add("visible")
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

First, I've prepared the CSS classes I'm going to use to hide/reveal the HTML element. They're in the head tag, traditional position for CSS. Javascript on the end of body tag. Script goes on the bottom so the elements it references are already rendered on the website beforehand. There are other CSS properties that you could use, see the [w3schools tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_class_display.asp) and documentation. I's a great resource for all the webdev stuff including JS and HTML.

Now the JS. First thing it does is create an variables containing the state of your selects by targeting their ids. Ids are supposed to be unique on the website (HTML itself does not care and lets you use one multiple times), so it assumes the target is also singular. You can then use several methods to pull info about state of the element and change it's properties, including the list of CSS classes or options value. So when clicking on the first select, I'll check if you've selected gold and then switch the CSS classess on the second element.

Best of luck on your journey trough the web development!